# Unknown admin password

Tags: password, permissions, automatic

I wanted to make an new Admin profile and delete the old one (long story), but I forgot to set a password. Now I can only enter Guest session and the Administrator account is asking me about a password I haven't even set! What is the password that Ubuntu automatically sets for a new Admin profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can boot with a live-cd and then mount the partition of your instalation with

> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/

(/dev/sda1 ist an example you have to figure out where your instalation is)

Then you have to chroot in the mounted system with

> chroot /mnt

And with

> passwd

you can set a new password for the root user.

Remember to unmount the filesystem when you are done

> sudo umount /mnt